# the path of current firefox profile using vbs in windows

Tags: javascript, windows, batch-file, firefox, vbscript

how can i navigate to the current profile directory of Firefox using java script or know the name folder profile in windows , because the profile name changed randomly for each user

Comment: `%AppData%\Mozilla\Firefox\profiles.ini` contains each profile *Name*, *IsRelative*, *Path* and the *Default* profile selected. This is what *Firefox* uses and suggest what a script would use. The Default profile path could be on a network path or somewhere else, so searching under the `Profiles` subfolder may not achieve a correct result. A portable Firefox probably looks in its own directory for a config file if you handle a portable version.

Answer (score 0):

With a batch file you can try like this :

```dos
@echo off
Color 0E & Mode con cols=107 lines=10
Title Find Cache Folder and File on Mozilla Firefox by Hackoo
echo(
Set "Profile_Folder=%AppData%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\"
CD /D "%Profile_Folder%"
Set "Pattern=cache*"
set "Cache_Path=%~dp0Cache_Path.txt"
For /f %%f in ('Where /R %Profile_Folder% "%Pattern%" /F') Do (
    Set "Cache_Folder=%%~dpf"
    Set "Cache_File=%%f"
)
echo Folder Cache : "%Cache_Folder%"
echo(
echo File Cache : %Cache_File% 
(
    echo Cache_Folder : "%Cache_Folder%"
    echo File Cache : %Cache_File% 
)> %Cache_Path%
Start "" "%Cache_Path%" & pause>nul
```